# Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string [XAF ListViewFilter]

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, xaf

I upgraded from framework to .NetCore with XAF 21.2.5

Now if I try to use the following ListViewFilter

```
 [ListViewFilter("Today",
        "[Created] >= LocalDateTimeToday()",
        "Today", true, Index = 0)]
```

on my business object which has properties

```
public DateTime Created { get; set; }
```

I get an error

```
  Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
  HResult=0x80131904
  Message=Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
  Source=Core Microsoft SqlClient Data Provider
  StackTrace:
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
```

The [docs](https://docs.devexpress.com/eXpressAppFramework/112809/filtering/in-list-view/how-to-use-function-criteria-operators-to-filter-list-views?p=net5) indicate this should work

[Update]

After reading [this question](https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/ticket/details/t737816/datagrid-the-conversion-failed-when-converting-date-and-or-time-from-character-string) I started experimenting with

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>().Property(x => x.Created).HasColumnType("datetime");
```

I am searching for the nullable one so as to map all the datetime properties.

Comment: have you made sure all data in db are valid dates?

Comment: I tried updating them all to the current date.

Comment: reading https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/entity-properties?tabs=data-annotations%2Cwithout-nrt

Answer (score 6):

The solution turned out to be to add the following to the OnModelCreating

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>().Property(x => x.Created).HasColumnType("datetime");
```

And to carefully check each declared property in the entity to ensure that I had whether or not it was nullable set correctly

I had an int? incorrectly declared as an int